# Jasmine.js comparing arrays

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Is there a way in jasmine.js to check if two arrays are equal, for example:

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]
expect(arr).toBe([1, 2, 3])
expect(arr).toEqual([1, 2, 3])
```

Neither seems to work.

Answer (score 370, accepted):

Just did the test and it works with `toEqual`

please find my test:

http://jsfiddle.net/7q9N7/3/

```
describe('toEqual', function() {
    it('passes if arrays are equal', function() {
        var arr = [1, 2, 3];
        expect(arr).toEqual([1, 2, 3]);
    });
});
```

**Just for information:**

> toBe() versus toEqual(): toEqual() checks equivalence. toBe(), on the
>   other hand, makes sure that they're the exact same object.

Comment: Hm, thanks, it seems that the problem is that the array I'm comparing to is modified, so it does something like arr = [1, 2, 3] arr['pop'] = function() { ... } expect(arr).toEquals([1, 2, 3])

Comment: how to test if values are equal within epsilon? e.g., my test fails Expected [ -9, -6, 6, 3, 1.0000000000000004, 2 ] to equal [ -9, -6, 6, 3, 1, 2 ].

Comment: @morpheus - I've tried `toBeCloseTo(expected,2)` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: the second argument of toBeCloseTo is the # of decimal places it will compare upto.

Comment: this falls back on "==" in javascript by default. This is just not safe since not only the actual values are compared, but the whole object.

Answer (score 2):

You can compare an array like the below mentioned if the array has some values

```
it('should check if the array are equal', function() {
        var mockArr = [1, 2, 3];
        expect(mockArr ).toEqual([1, 2, 3]);
 });
```

But if the array that is returned from some function has more than 1 elements and all are zero then verify by using

```
expect(mockArray[0]).toBe(0);
```

Answer (score -2):

just for the record you can always compare using JSON.stringify

`const arr = [1,2,3];
expect(JSON.stringify(arr)).toBe(JSON.stringify([1,2,3]));
expect(JSON.stringify(arr)).toEqual(JSON.stringify([1,2,3]));`

It's all meter of taste, 
this will also work for complex literal objects

Comment: why would we need a difference between toBe and toEqual then?

Comment: there is no difference , I just wante'd to let it look like the question

Comment: There is a difference between toBe and toEqual the OP was unsure about. An answer should clarify things, rather than showing improper use. The accepted answer already contains it all, your answer potentially introduces more confusion showing how to force jasmine to work in a way that it's not intended to work.

Answer (score -4):

I had a similar issue where one of the arrays was modified. I was using it for `$httpBackend`, and the returned object from that was actually a `$promise` object containing the array (not an `Array` object).

You can create a jasmine matcher to match the array by creating a `toBeArray` function:

```
beforeEach(function() {
  'use strict';
  this.addMatchers({
    toBeArray: function(array) {
      this.message = function() {
        return "Expected " + angular.mock.dump(this.actual) + " to be array " + angular.mock.dump(array) + ".";
      };
      var arraysAreSame = function(x, y) {
         var arraysAreSame = true;
         for(var i; i < x.length; i++)
            if(x[i] !== y[i])
               arraysAreSame = false;
         return arraysAreSame;
      };
      return arraysAreSame(this.actual, array);
    }
  });
});
```

And then just use it in your tests like the other jasmine matchers:

```
it('should compare arrays properly', function() {
  var array1, array2;
  /* . . . */
  expect(array1[0]).toBe(array2[0]);
  expect(array1).toBeArray(array2);
});
```

Comment: I'm getting TypeError: this.addMatchers is not a function

Comment: The "arraysAreSame" function you have provided will give a false positive for the arrays `x=[1,2]`, `y=[1,2,3]` since it only checks the first `x.length` elements. You can fix this by checking `if (x.length !== y.length) { return false; }` beforehand.

Comment: @AndyTheEntity "The addMatchers function is no longer on the spec (this) it is now on the global jasmine object." - see [Jasmine docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/upgrading.html)

Comment: `for (var i; ...)` => `x[undefined]`, `var arraysAreSame = function ... var arraysAreSame = true` :(

Comment: @warchinal funny, it also fails to catch `expect([1]).toBeArray([2])`. And also any other array really, because `undefined + 1 => NaN`

Comment: @AndréWerlang actually that's because `.toBeArray()` is a function that takes no arguments, and just tells you if (in your case) `[1]` is an array, which it is. I think you meant to do `expect([1]).toEqual([2])`, which would of course fail

Comment: @warchinal no, that's not it. See my 2 previous comments, it's pretty obvious that `i` isn't initialized