# Testing Angular resource in Karma fails with "Expected [ ] to equal [ ]"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine, ngresource, angularjs-ng-resource

I'm trying to perform a very basic unit test on an Angular resource:

```
describe('coupons.resource', function () {
    var Coupons, $httpBackend;

    beforeEach(function () {
        module('coupons.resource');
        inject(function (_Coupons_, _$httpBackend_) {
            Coupons = _Coupons_;
            $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        });
    });

    it('should return empty array if it receives empty array', function () {
        $httpBackend.expectGET(/admin\/coupons/).respond([]);
        Coupons.query().$promise.then(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            expect(data).toEqual([]);            
        });

        $httpBackend.flush();        
    });
});
```

Coupons is a resource.  The test above fails with the error:

```
Expected [] to equal []
```

The console output confirms that data expected is indeed an empty array.  This seems so trivial.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717844/jasmine-js-comparing-arrays) your code should work, can you provide plunkr or js fiddle?

Comment: @Grundy, I'm not sure how I would set up a Plunkr or JS Fiddle for a Karma test runner.  I've never seen one like that before, have you?  Also, I don't believe this is an issue with comparing two arrays.  I think this has to do with the asynchronous nature of Angular resources, but I could be wrong.